# Exclude hash calculation for some file using MAGE command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, mage

In Visual Studio, when I pubish a ClickOnce application I have the Application Files dialog box, here I can choose to exclude the hash calcualtion for some of the files (I do that for a config file as I want to be able to change it on client site).

This works fine for me but I would like to do that using mage (command line or ui), I dont see any option in mage to exclude the hash calculation for some file, is it possible?

Thanks!